# JavaFX TextField android stuck

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

I've benn using JavaFX for a couple of days and now I have a problem with text field on android.

I have a very basic application with only one text field. When I click on it to type some text, everything is fine.
[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgTJU.png)

But when I fineshed typing and click on other items UI stucks. Animations are not displayed. When i click on text field again, keyboard appears without problems, I can type, I can hear the usual sound of typing on android, but UI is still stuck and visually textfield is not changing [as you an see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCCIs.png).

Magic happens when I turn off display and turn it on again. After that i can see that everything that i typed is inside of TextField. UI is not stuck and text that i type is displayed correctly. But when i click on anouther button it breaks as first time.

Additionally i tried to use TextField from *javafx.scene.control* and *com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control*  and they both don't work.

Code that I am using:
BasicView.java

```
package com.gluonapplication;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField;

public class BasicView extends View
{
    TextField field;

    public BasicView(String name)
    {
        super(name);

        field = new TextField();
        setTop(field);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar)
    {
        appBar.setTitleText("Basic View");
        appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.SEARCH.button(e -> System.out.println("Search")));
    }
}
```

GluonApplication.java

```
package com.gluonapplication;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.Swatch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GluonApplication extends MobileApplication
{
    public static final String BASIC_VIEW = HOME_VIEW;

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        addViewFactory(BASIC_VIEW, () -> new BasicView(BASIC_VIEW));
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(Scene scene) {
        Swatch.BLUE.assignTo(scene);
        ((Stage) scene.getWindow()).getIcons().add(new Image(GluonApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.9'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:3.0.0'

    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-android:3.0.0'
    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-ios:3.0.0'
    desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:3.0.0'
}

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = 'D:\\AMAZING_THINGS\\AndroidSdk'
        compileSdkVersion = '16'
    }
}
```

So, the question is how to reach that "screen turning off/on" effect? I feel like it is connected with losing focus and updating UI, but I'm not sure.
Thx for your time.

I am using Android 4.1.1, java 8

Comment: This could be a problem with Android 4 and the used javafxportsversion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361644/textfield-focus-issue-on-javafxports-8-60-7

Comment: @jns Thank you! It works fine with javafxportsVersion = '8.60.6'
Should I use it or there is better versions?

Comment: I'm still using 8.60.6, since I have found no other solution. Overall, it seems javafxports works best with Android from version 5 on.

Comment: @jns okay. Thank you one more time

Comment: this bug seems to be resolved in javafxportsVersion 8.60.8